# Breaking the square root of an integral

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus

Im am having a difficult time trying to solve the following integral because i cant seem to break or get rid of the square root.

$$\int \sqrt{\frac{x^2}{4}+\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{4x^2}}dx$$

Comment: Add up the terms inside of the radical, then factor the numerator.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint:
$$\frac{x^2}4+\frac12+\frac{1}{4x^2}=\left(\frac{x}2+\frac{1}{2x}\right)^2$$

So,
$$\sqrt{\frac{x^2}4+\frac12+\frac{1}{4x^2}}=\frac12\left|x+\frac{1}{x}\right|$$
and the integral becomes easy to evaluate.

Comment: Should be the absolute value.

Answer (score 0):

The integrand (thing inside the square root) is $\sqrt{(\frac{1}{2}(x+\frac{1}{x}))^2}$.

Answer (score 0):

remark that under the square symbol,
it's a square of the form
A^2+2AB+B^2 which is equal to

(A+B)^2

then the evaluation will become easier.